# Mirror monitors 2 and 3?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, desktop, mirroring

I have an Asus laptop and two 24" monitors.  One plugged into HDMI and the other VGA.  When I go into my display properties I have 3 options

- Mirror 1 and 3
- Mirror 1 and 2
- Extend Desktop

I've also scoured through the NVidia control panel and didn't see anything.

Is there any way, either natively or with additional software, to mirror 2 and 3?